# WolframAlpha says that $\sum^n_{k-1}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor \phi(k) \not = \sum^n_{k=1}k$ which is not true

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, wolfram-alpha

I submitted the following query to WolframAlpha:

> Is sum Floor[n/k]Phi[k], k=1 to n equal to sum k, k to n

and [the result (link)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+sum+Floor%5Bn%2Fk%5DPhi%5Bk%5D,+k%3D1+to+n+equal+to+sum+k,+k+to+n) was:

> $\sum^n_{k-1}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor \phi(k)$ is not always equal to $\sum^n_{k=1}k$

The interesting thing is that it is not true according to the solutions presented in:

- *[Euler phi Function and Floor Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155433/euler-phi-function-and-floor-function)*.
- *[Identity involving Euler's totient function: $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor \varphi(k) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/identity-involving-eulers-totient-function-sum-limits-k-1n-left-lfloor?rq=1)*.

What happened? Is it a bug, or there are some edge cases that WolframAlpha is taking under account?

Comment: Mathematica (and therefore WolframAlpha I presume) is not able to simplify the sum down to $n(n+1)/2$ so thats probably the reason it returns false. Returning "I don't know" would probably have been a better answer.

Comment: @Winther This is why I am asking. WolframAlpha should not say that they are not always equal.

Comment: It is known that Worlfram alpha makes sometimes mistakes.

Comment: @N.S. Perfect, I guess I just have to notify the WolframAlpha dev team now.

Comment: I think that this mistake was pointed to them couple years back, still not fixed :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+floor+x

Comment: @N.S. Interesting. Even the newest Mathematica (version 11) gives strange values for the derivative of the floor function at non-integer values. For example $\text{Floor}'(1.1) = -4.29$ apposed to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submitted this bug to the WolframAlpha team.

This is their response:

> We appreciate your feedback regarding Wolfram|Alpha. The issue you
>   reported has been passed along to our development team for review.
>   Thank you for helping us improve Wolfram|Alpha.